# How to solve this using algebraic representation? $((p∧q)→r)↔((p→r)∨(q→r))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I need to solve this equation for a discrete math class. We were not taught how to use "algebraic representation". Can someone help me with this and the rules?

$$((p∧q)→r)↔((p→r)∨(q→r))$$

Comment: What are the rules that you can use? Can you use a truth table maybe?

Comment: No, we can not use a truth table for this. The instructor wants to use "algebraic representation".

Comment: For example, He showed us this: (p∧q)∨r is the same as pq+r-pqr. which doesn't make sense if he used algebra for this. I'm very confused.

Comment: OK, so what algebraic rules were given to you? .... wait, do I read that right? You were *not* taught how to use "algebraic representation"?!?

Comment: Yes, we were given an example and no real explanation. For example, He showed us this: (p∧q)∨r is the same as pq+r-pqr. if (p*q)+r then where does the minus comes from?

Comment: Wow, so not only did he change the notation, but also didn't give you the basic algebraic principles/rules that are behind this?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Well, that is very frustrating to say the least .... can you contact your instructor and ask him for a list of basic principles?  Otherwise you are really just swimming in the dark ...

Comment: I spent hours trying to find algebraic notations that match his example, but I haven't been able to find them. I would appreciate help with solving the main example so I can use that as an example for next week's final exam (yes, I have final exam).

Comment: Any time we (class) ask questions, he says "read the book" and dismisses us. There is nothing of this sort in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I really hate to have to do the work of your instructor, but here is how to make sense of your example:

If you treat 'True' as a $1$, 'False' as a $0$, then note that the logical $\land$ 'matches' multiplication for integers:

\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
p&q&(p \land q)&pq\\
\hline
T&T&T \land T = T&1*1=1\\
T&F&T \land F = F&1*0=0\\
F&T&F \land T = F&0*1=0\\
F&F&F \land F = F&0*0=0\\
\end{array}

The logical $\lor$ is *almost* addition .. you just need to do a small correction for when both sides are true (so this is where the subtraction comes in):

\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
p&q&(p \lor q)&p+q-pq\\
\hline
T&T&T \lor T = T&1+1-1*1=1+1-1=1\\
T&F&T \lor F = T&1+0-1*0=1+0-0=1\\
F&T&F \lor T = T&0+1-0*1=0+1-0=1\\
F&F&F \lor F = F&0+0-0*0=0+0-0=0\\
\end{array}

So now you can understand the mapping between $(p \land q) \lor r$ and $pq + r - pqr$:

$(p \land q) \lor r = (p \land q) + r - (p \land q)*r = p * q + r - (p * q) * r = pq + r - pqr$:

Verify:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
p&q&r&(p \land q) \lor r&pq + r - pqr\\
\hline
T&T&T&(T\land T)\lor T = T \lor T = T&1*1+1-1*1*1=1+1-1=1\\
T&T&F&(T\land T)\lor F = T \lor F = T&1*1+0-1*1*0=1+0-0=1\\
T&F&T&(T\land F)\lor T = F \lor T = T&1*0+1-1*0*1=0+1-0=1\\
T&F&F&(T\land F)\lor F = F \lor F = F&1*0+0-1*0*0=0+0-0=0\\
F&T&T&(F\land T)\lor T = F \lor T = T&0*1+1-0*1*1=0+1-0=1\\
F&T&F&(F\land T)\lor F = F \lor F = F&0*1+0-0*1*0=0+0-0=0\\
F&F&T&(F\land F)\lor T = F \lor T = T&0*0+1-0*0*1=0+1-0=1\\
F&F&F&(F\land F)\lor F = F \lor F = F&0*0+0-0*0*0=0+0-0=0\\
\end{array}

OK, so now the question is how to treat other connectives like $\neg$ and  $\to$.

Well, the $\neg$ is fairly straightforward: $\neg p = 1 - p$

And since $p \to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$, you thus get: $p \to q = \neg p \lor q = (1-p) + q - (1-p)q=1-p+q-q+pq=1-p+pq$

OK, hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant! Can you explain why a) (∧)∨ is the same as b) +−? I don't understand how we got from a to b...

Comment: @Mathhh Yup!  I just added that to the post :)

Comment: Thank you so much! YOU saved me!

Comment: Am I able to rewrite "((→)∨(→))" as "(p∧q)→r" based on logical equivalence involving conditional statements to further simplify and solve the main problem?

Comment: Well, it sounds like your instructor wants you to immediately replace the logical expressions with their integer operation counterparts, and show the equivalence on that side. So, it seems like you shouldn't be using any logical equivalence principles at all in your answer. In other words, work our what the left logical expression would be in terms of mathematical expression, and do the same for the right side, and then show the two are equal using good old high school math algebra

Comment: Got it. I have one more question. Is this correct? (p∧q)→r same as ¬(p∧q) ∨ r and same as 1-(pq+r-pqr)

Comment: Let’s see … I get $(1-pq) +r -(1-pq)r= 1-pq+r-r+pqr=1-pq+pqr$ …. But I am kind of rusty with high school math :)

Comment: Ok, right side: $(p \to r)\lor (q \to r)=1-p+pr+1-q+qr-(1-p+pr)(1-q+qr)=1-p+pr+1-q+qr-1+q-qr+p-pq+pqr-pr+pqr-pqr^2=1-pq+2pqr-pqr^2$. Noting that values of variables are always $0$ or $1$, we have that $r^2=r$, and so we get $1-pq+2pqr-pqr=1-pq+pqr$. Hey hey! :)

Comment: This is the best explanation. Thank you so much. I'm now ready to face the exam.

Comment: @Mathhh  Glad I was able to help :) (But I'm still miffed at your instrucor :(  )  You can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of my answer. Good luck with your exam!!

Comment: I will accept the answer. Thank you again.